# How to fetch id of softdeleted data in laravel 4.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, soft-delete

Sending Id through ajax

```
 <script language="javascript">
    var xmlHttp;
    function Rtask(id) {
        xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
        if(xmlHttp==null) {
            alert("browser do not support ajax");
            return;
        }

        var url='releaseleader/'+id;
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged;
        xmlHttp.open("POST",url,true);
        xmlHttp.send(null);
        return false;
    }


    function GetXmlHttpObject()
    {
        var objXMLHttp=null;
        if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            objXMLHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else if(window.ActiveXObject)
        {
            objXMLHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        return objXMLHttp;
    }
</script>
```

Route->

```
       Route::Post('releaseleader/{id}','TeamController@releaseleader');
```

Model->

```
 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingTrait;

 class Tasktime extends Eloquent

 {
public $table='tasktime';
use SoftDeletingTrait;

protected $softDelete = true;

protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];     }
```

Controller

```
public function releaseleader($id)
{

    $leader=Tasktime::find($id);
    $leader->delete();


        return Redirect::to('managertask/'.$id);
}
```

For example After softdelete it is not redirected to page with id such as managertask/17

But Before softdlete it is redirecting to page having id 17

Please help me

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific with your question.  Does the `$id` variable exist inside the `releaseleader` method in your controller?

Comment: Added few more details

Comment: @V4n1ll4 Added more details

Comment: Have you checked if `$id` exists at the top of your `releaseleader()` method?  Do a die and dump `dd($id);`

Comment: yes it exist.i have checked

Comment: @V4n1II4 It is showing string(2) "30"

Comment: what is the value of $id before and after the redirect?

Answer (score 0):

Eloquent automatically ignores soft-deleted rows. You can tell it not do by chaining the `withTrashed()` method. In your case:

```
$leader = Tasktime::withTrashed()->find($id);
```

Comment: have you look at the deleted_at field if there is data exist (not null)?, if yes, then the problem maybe caused by eloquent that ignores soft-deleted rows.